# Missing plugin for GStreamer for Android SDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer

I changed the stream url in the included *Tutorial 5* (a basic media player) to a h.264/mp3 media stream (from its original ogv stream) and it started complaining about some missing plugins.

After doing some googling I found Prajnashi's gst-ffmpeg plugin for Android https://github.com/prajnashi/gst-ffmpeg but it is certainly not suitable for the SDK.

If the SDK does not have the required plugin how do I go about resolving this? I am new to GStreamer and have no idea how to compile any of the existing plugins for Android.

Comment: I have the same problem now. Have you solved this one? Please let me know your solution.

Comment: I am afraid not. No reply from GstreamerSDK either.

Comment: found a solution to this in the meantime ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add

```
$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED)
```

to your Android.mk in the jni folder for android-tutorial-5

Like so:

```
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)  $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED)
```