# How can I get gstreamer-plugins into it's Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer

I need gstreamer for decoding H.264 video on rtp, so I used the SDK from gstreamer.com. But I found that something I need is not included, such as 264depay, x264dec, etc.. I found gst-plugins on http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/, I think I need to compile it in Android form, and it has Android.mk inside. What should I do to deal with it? Tried execute ndk-build, but failed.

Many thanks.

Comment: this problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994808/missing-plugin-for-gstreamer-for-android-sdk?rq=1